# Premium Responsive Drupal 6 themes?

Tags: theming

Where can I find Premium Responsive Drupal 6 themes?

(CSS defined in such a way that the same stylesheet is used on mobile and desktop)

It must be Drupal 6 because I am using it with [drupal-cod](http://usecod.com).

Answer (score 0):

Update 1: As pointed out by the OP, Jeff Burnz doesn't only sell his time as a consultant, but actually has a site, [AdaptiveThemes.com](http://adaptivethemes.com/), where he sells his "adaptive"-themes, but those are D7 only.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any company advertising such themes yet.
One of the first I would except to see this from is http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/, but nothing there yet.

If you are looking for something more unique, I believe the Drupal 8 Design Initiative owner, [Jeff Burnz](http://drupal.org/user/61393), sells his time to make themes, and is the author of a number of responsive themes already. [Sky](http://drupal.org/project/sky), [Corolla](http://drupal.org/project/corolla) and the base theme [Adaptive theme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme), which you may want to look into, given the lack of an actual answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff Burnz's [Memento](http://adaptivethemes.com/new-designs) seems good, but is 3 months overdue and seems to be Drupal 7 only. I will look into the others, and keep an eye on this Question.

Comment: Jeff got back to me, nothing he makes is compatible with Drupal 6.